# Not getting expected results from for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm making a javascript neural network and trying to put some entries into an object using for loops but I'm not getting the result I want.
I want to be able to get an object looking like:

```
{0 : {neuron1Sum : null}}
```

And I want to loop it to create multiple neurons and layers. It might be easier to understand once you see the code.

```
hiddenLayers : function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        numberOfNeurons = arguments[i];
        hiddenLayer = {};

        for (var j = 0; j < numberOfNeurons - 1; j++) {
            hiddenLayer[i] = ["neuron" + j + "Sum"];
            hiddenLayer[i]["neuron" + j + "Sum"] = null;
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: What result _are_ you getting?

Comment: @MattBall I'm getting {2 : {neuron1Sum : null}} and that's all. It's not filling in the rest.

Comment: Just a small pointer, you can use `arguments.map` instead of outer loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hiddenLayer` should be defined as array and `hiddenLayer[i]` should be defined as object. Then put each element to object like this way.

```
hiddenLayers : function() {
    var hiddenLayer = []; // defined as array
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        numberOfNeurons = arguments[i];
        hiddenLayer[i] = {}; //defined as object
        for (var j = 0; j < numberOfNeurons - 1; j++) {
            hiddenLayer[i]["neuron" + j + "Sum"] = null;
        }
    }
    return hiddenLayer;
    /*
    will return something like :

        [
            0 : {neuron1Sum : null, neuron2Sum : null},
            1 : {neuron1Sum : null, neuron2Sum : null}
        ] 
    */
},
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to move a couple identifiers around and initialise an *Array* before the inner loop

```
// ...
hiddenLayers: function() {
    var numberOfNeurons,
        hiddenLayer = [], // keep this across all the loops
        temp, // to store objects as we make them
        i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        numberOfNeurons = arguments[i];
        hiddenLayer[i] = []; // remember to initialise
        for (j = 0; j < numberOfNeurons - 1; ++j) {
            temp = {};
            temp["neuron" + j + "Sum"] = null;
            hiddenLayer[i].push(temp);
        }
    }
    return hiddenLayer; // remember to return
},
// ...
```

This code now produces something like

```
[
    [
        {neuron0Sum: null},
        {neuron1Sum: null}
    ],
    [
        {neuron0Sum: null},
        {neuron1Sum: null}
    ]
]
```

---

Starting in ES6 we will be able to use expressions in the property names of *Object literals*, e.g.

```
{
    ["foo" + "bar"]: "baz"
}
// produces
{
    "foobar": "baz"
}
```

If you want your code to work in production right now, don't use this feature yet (maybe in a year or two)

Comment: I get an unexpected token error for "+" on the line that says hiddenLayer[i].push({"neuron" + j + "Sum": null});

Comment: @Iceclaw12 please see if the code does as desired now :)

Comment: Thankyou so much! it works well. How do I accept your answer?

Comment: Once your question is 15 minutes old you will be able to select an accepted answer, in the mean time don't forget to see if you think any other answer is more applicable and upvote all answers you found useful.

Comment: This is an awesome answer except the one I have accepted makes objects instead of arrays which is what I wanted and also it's a bit shorter. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that code is doing what you want, but I'm not sure what you want..

This assignment:

```
hiddenLayer[i] = ["neuron" + j + "Sum"];
```

sets `hiddenLayer[i]` to an array containing a single string.  It's equivalent to this:

```
hiddenLayer[i] = [];
hiddenLayer[i][0] = "neuron" + j + "Sum";
```

Then this assignment:

```
hiddenLayer[i]["neuron" + j + "Sum"] = null;
```

Treats `hiddenLayer[i]` as a generic Object (associative array, map, hash, dictionary) and sets a named property (with the same name as that string) to `null`. So if `i` is 0 and `j` is 0, you get an object that looks like this:

```
{  
  0: "neuron0Sum",
  neuron0Sum: null
}
```

I suspect that's not what you're trying to accomplish...